# AWS VPC - DHCP Default Gateway Option

Tags: amazon-web-services, gateway, dhcp, amazon-vpc

so, I'm working with a proprietary device in which I don't have direct control over the device's network gateway setting. I learned that it pulls the gateway setting from the DHCP options set on the network.

Our network is built on AWS, inside a VPC. I'm thinking of updating the DHCP options, but it doesn't seem to have a setting for Gateway (image shows all available options). Does anyone know if there's a way to specify the Gateway for AWS VPC?

The device is connected to our cloud through a virtual private gateway.

[image]

Comment: I had prepared an answer but now I'm not sure I was answering your actual question.  Whose default route are you trying to control?  If you are trying to control the default route of this external device, on the other side of a VPN connection, there's no possible way that it is pulling DHCP from VPC, so even if you could change this setting here, it would not have the desired effect.  These settings are only relevant to instances.  The only way an external device could be using DHCP at all would be on the *local* network where it's connected, outside of VPC.  Please clarify.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. I think at the time I didn't really understand what a gateway was doing - I get that it connects a network to the internet (or just to a different network) - my issue was hostname resolution, and since the DNS server setting was right on this device and the only difference between it and a different type of device that could resolve the hostname correctly was the gateway setting, I assumed that the gateway setting was incorrect. I was wrong - hostname resolution started up, after I had changed nothing, so it seems like it was probably a caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this is simply not possible within an Amazon VPC, as they use DHCP for all of their IP assignments within a VPC subnet, static IP addresses are assigned by using [Elastic Network Interfaces](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html), which work in the same way as a DHCP reservation. Amazon Support will be able to confirm this though, so I'd suggest you contact them.

But you can specify a gateway for a subnet in your AWS VPC.

Your next-best solution is to create a virtual network on the Windows box, using the [Loopback Adapter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/df1dbf9f-58fa-4ac1-b019-8f86863371b7/ms-loopback-adapter-windows-server-2008?forum=winservergen). You can then create a DHCP scope on this network, and essentially dual-home the box.

To create a NIC using the loopback driver (from the link above):

Start -> Computer -> Right-click, Properties -> Device Manager -> Computer Name, Right-click, Add Legacy Hardware -> Next -> Install the hardware I manually select from a list -> Next -> Network Adapters -> Microsoft on the right, Loopback adapter on the left -> Next

If you are using a Linux box refer this guide this might also help.

http://imsudo.com/how-to-configure-loopback-interface-in-linux-windows/

Once you have two functioning networks, it should be relatively straightforward to configure your RRAS clients to receive a DHCP address from the virtual scope and route to the Internet via your Amazon VPC's default gateway.

Comment: This is a good answer - I'm looking into specifying a gateway for the subnet. The device isn't actually a Windows box, I suspect it's running a unix variant but I can't confirm. I only have remote access and can only see some pretty basic settings. Thanks for the thoughtful response and level of detail

Comment: Did you check this scenario http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario3.html I edited my answer too.

Comment: I read through the links you provided, learned a lot of good information. I wound up not having to change the gateway setting after all, I thought it was messing up hostname resolution, but I think the DNS server needed it's cache refreshed and just wasn't configured to do that very often. Thanks for all your help!